# Access env var from docker file to react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, devops

I have a docker file -

```
FROM nginx:latest
ENV API_URL $API_URL
COPY deployment-configs/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf ./*
COPY packages/Project/Container/dist .
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

with env variables as API_URL

And manifest file

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
  labels:
    app: kubesphere
    component: ui-dev
    tier: frontend
  name: ui-dev
  namespace: Test Project
spec:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubesphere
      component: ui-dev
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubesphere
        component: ui-dev
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: API_URL
              value: http://192.40.84.98:5656
          image: $REGISTRY/$HARBOR_NAMESPACE/$APP_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION-$BUILD_NUMBER
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Now I want to access this API_URL in my react application.
This is what I have done so far -

In webpack -

```
 plugins: [
    new Dotenv({ path: '.env' }),
    new DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL) }),
  ],
```

And in my react application -

I am using this variable as
`process.env.API_URL`

but it is giving me `undefined`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can you help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug if the environment variables exist in the docker container or the webpack config file? If there is no `.env` file mount to the container, `dotenv-webpack` plugin is unneccesary

Comment: @LinDu Yes, I have used a plugin called Dotenv in webpack file which is as follows -

new Dotenv({ path: '.env' }),

And this is .env file - 

API_URL=http://192.40.84.98:5656
ENVIRONMENT=DEVELOPMENT

I am able to get this API_URL in my application from .env. But not sure what else I need to do to get it from docker file.

Comment: `DefinePlugin` replaces variables in your code with other values or expressions at `compile` time, not runtime. So, build the application using webpack at the build stage with environment variables, `process.env.API_URL` will be replaced. At runtime, the replaced value is already there. Copy the `dist` at the release stage

Comment: I may be wrong here but devops people says that I don't need to set the parameters at build time, this will be set automatically at runtime.  I just need to access this API_URL in my application.